# animation with img and txt in html5

Tags: html, slideshow

I am trying this to make a sildeshow (as shown in w3school), but, in my slideshow, I have both img and txt(side by side in large screen), and this is not working.

If I simply define 
 and no text at all, e.g. then its working fine,but not with below html and css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="anime">
  <div id="animg">
    <img src="hds1.jpg" style="height:30vh;"/>
  </div>
  <div id="antxt">Hello1</div>
  <div id="animg">
    <img src="hds2.jpg" style="height:30vh;"/>
  </div>
  <div id="antxt">Hello2</div>
  <div id="animg">
    <img src="hds3.jpg" style="height:30vh;"/>
  </div>
  <div id="antxt">Hello3</div>
</div>

<script>
  var myIndex = 0;
  carousel();

  function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("animg");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
  }
</script>
```

and the css file:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2.0vw;
  color: #747271;
}

/* Animation */
.anime { 
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom:10vw;
  padding-top:4vw; 
  margin-left:3vw; 
  margin-right: 4vw; 
  display:none;
}
.anime div {
  min-height: 1vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  padding-top:4vw; 
  margin-left:3vw; 
  margin-right: 4vw; 
}
#animg {
  float: left;
  padding-right:4vw;
  margin-right: 4vw; 
  width: 10vw;
}
#antxt { 
  min-height:2.2vw;
  float: left;
  color:#747271; font-family:serif; font-size:2.0vw;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am trying to get the text and img side-by-side, and slide together; e.g. img hds1 and txt hello1 will appear in the screen in same time, and will slide for hds2 and hello2.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you said `document.getElementsByClassName`, but in your HTML you used IDs instead of classes. This should work for you:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <style>
    .mySlides {display:none;}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

    <div class="anime">
      <div class="animg">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="height:30vh;"/>
      </div>
      <div id="antxt">Hello1</div>
      <div class="animg">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="height:30vh;"/>
      </div>
      <div id="antxt">Hello2</div>
      <div class="animg">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="height:30vh;"/>
      </div>
      <div id="antxt">Hello3</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var myIndex = 0;
      carousel();

      function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("animg");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: The above is working for me (take note that I changed the images to placeholder images) - but I am not 100% of the behaviour that you are expecting. Perhaps you can explain further or send a link to what it is that you are trying to achieve?